# Is there a more efficient way than this way of if statements in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, repeat

I wonder (and I think there must be) if there is another way of comparing variables and changing them, because if I used "or" in the if statements, I don't have any way of determining which card made the statement True.

```
def card_value(card_one, card_two):

    if card_one == 'A':
        card_one = 11

    if card_two == 'A':
        card_two == 11

    if card_one in ('K', 'J', 'Q'):
        card_one = 10

    if card_two in ('K', 'J', 'Q'):
        card_two = 10
```

Comment: Let the function `card_value` handle one value, then two. Then call it twice, once per card.

Comment: You might also have a table (probably in a `dict`) which maps the AKJQ to the values

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `card_one` and `card_two` exist in a scope outside of the function `card_value`, so assigning them values within `card_value` won't be possible without re-declaring them as global variables within `card_value`. To treat this and simplify `card_value`, may I suggest re-writing `card_value` to take in any card and return the desired score?

```
def card_value(card):

    if card == 'A':
        return 11

    elif card in ('K', 'J', 'Q'):
        return 10

def main():
    card_one = 'A'
    card_two = 'Q'
    
    card_one_points = card_value(card_one)
    card_two_points = card_value(card_two)

main()
```

Comment: For the pip cards, the `card_value` function might return `int(card)` ?

Comment: Luckily Python is dynamically typed, so ```card_value``` will be able to process integer input as well just by adding more ```if``` statements to describe how to do so.